# Group the list of Objects and convert to a map using java8

Tags: collections, java-8, grouping

`Hi,

I have a list of Employees employeeList (assume this list has some values present)

```
List<Employee> employeeList ;
```

Say, My Employee DTO is something like below :

```
Employee {
List<Book> bookList;
}
```

Book DTO:

```
Book {
private String bookId;
private String bookName;
}
```

I have to stream through the employeeList and group the employees with same book Id and convert to a map having key as the BookId and value as list of Employees.
I want to achieve this using java8 concepts. Please help!

I tried to use Collectors.groupingBy but I have to traverse through another List of Books inside list of Employees.
Could not figure out how?`

Comment: Please, share your **attempt** and specify the problem you've encountered. Every question on StackOverflow is expected to demonstrate an effort. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flatten the Employee list to pairs of Employee, Book ID and then collect to the Map you want.

Something like this (not tested):

```
Map<String,List<Employee>> map =
    employeeList.stream()
                .flatMap(e -> e.getBookList()
                               .stream()
                               .map(book -> new SimpleEntry<String,Employee>(book.getID (), e)))
                .collect (Collectors.groupingBy (Map.Entry::getKey,
                                                 Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                                                                    Collectors.toList())));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with flatmapping, capturing a "bookId to employee" pair (you can use a temporary `record` as of newer Java or `SimpleEntry` with Java 8), grouping by the `bookId` and mapping to the final structure (`List<Employee>` to `Employee`).

```java
record BookEmployee(String bookId, Employee employee) {}

Map<String, List<Employee>> map = employeeList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.flatMapping(
                e -> e.getBookList()
                      .stream()
                      .map(b -> new BookEmployee(b.getBookId(), e)),
                Collectors.groupingBy(
                        BookEmployee::bookId,
                        Collectors.mapping(
                                BookEmployee::employee, 
                                Collectors.toList()))));
```